# PROBLEMAS PARA HACER CONEXION CON DOS BASES DE DATOS DE ACCESS CON VBA EXCEL

Tags: base-de-datos, vba, ms-access

*buen dia he tratado de hacer el vinculo de dos base de datos pero solamente he podido hacer una consulta 'con una  donde me trae el "id" y le va incrementado 1 para que este no se repita apartir del libro de 'excel donde se le van poniendo datos.  Apartir de Set cn2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") conexion2 = '"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _ "Data Source=C:\Users\Asus-PC\Desktop\SICAP\Current 'Information\MaterialCost.mdb"  consultaSql2 = "Select cost from MatCost WHERE PartNumber = ' " & 'numero_de_parte & " ' " es donde tengo el problema el query no obtiene el valor de la otra base de datos 'en el  libro de tiene el valor del cual se basara para obtenerlo (esta en la celda)*

```
Sub consultarAccess()
      introducir el código aquíDim cn As Object
     Dim cn2 As Object
       Dim datos As Object**texto en negrita**
       Dim datos2 As Object
        Dim consultaSql  As String
       Dim consultaSql2  As String
        Dim conexion2 As String
        Dim conexion As String
        Dim cont As Long
        Dim maxSICAPCtrllnumber As Long
        Dim incremento_celda As Integer
        Dim fila_b As Integer
        Dim fila_c As Integer
        Dim fila_d As Integer
        Dim fila_e As Integer
        Dim fila_f As Integer
        Dim fila_g As Integer
        Dim fila_h As Integer
        Dim fila_i As Integer
        Dim fila_j As Integer
        Dim cost As Long



    fila_b = 7
    fila_c = 7
    fila_d = 7
    fila_e = 7
    fila_f = 7
    fila_g = 7
    fila_h = 7
    fila_i = 7
    fila_j = 7



      Do Until Cells(fila_b, 2) = Empty



        Tipo_de_producto = Cells(fila_b, 2)
        numero_de_serie = Cells(fila_b, 3)
        numero_de_parte = Cells(fila_b, 4)
        dprts = Cells(fila_b, 5)
        Entregado_por = Cells(fila_b, 6)
        tipo_de_queja = Cells(fila_b, 7)
        descripcion_de_la_queja = Cells(fila_b, 8)
        Asignados_a = Cells(fila_b, 9)
        cantidad = Cells(fila_b, 10)
        fecha_de_entrega_lab = Cells(fila_b, 11)
        costo_de_unidad = Cells(fila_b, 12)

        If Len(Tipo_de_producto) = 0 Or Len(numero_de_serie) = 0 Or Len(numero_de_parte) = 0 Or Len(dprts) = 0 Or Len(Entregado_por) = 0 Or Len(tipo_de_queja) = 0 Or Len(descripcion_de_la_queja) = 0 Or Len(Asignados_a) = 0 Or Len(cantidad) = 0 Or Len(fecha_de_entrega_lab) = 0 Then
            GoTo Err0r
            End If




        Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

        conexion = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\Asus-PC\Desktop\SICAP\Current Information\DdMCPE.mdb"

          consultaSql = "Select Max(SICAPCtrllnumber) from IDProducto"

         cn.Open conexion
         Set datos = cn.Execute(consultaSql)

         maxSICAPCtrllnumber = datos.Fields(0) + 1


         consultaSql = "insert into IDProducto(SICAPCtrllnumber,producttype,productSN,productPN,DPRTS,deliveredby,rejectsource,claim,analyst,quantity)  values (" & maxSICAPCtrllnumber & "," & "'" & Tipo_de_producto & "'" & "," & "'" & numero_de_serie & "'" & "," & "'" & numero_de_parte & "'" & "," & "'" & dprts & "'" & "," & "'" & Entregado_por & "'" & "," & "'" & tipo_de_queja & "'" & "," & "'" & descripcion_de_la_queja & "'" & "," & "'" & Asignados_a & "'" & "," & "'" & cantidad & "')"

         Set datos = cn.Execute(consultaSql)

         cn.Close
         Set datos = Nothing
        Set cn = Nothing
         ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Set cn2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")


     conexion2 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\Asus-PC\Desktop\SICAP\Current Information\MaterialCost.mdb"

             consultaSql2 = "Select cost from MatCost WHERE PartNumber = ' " & numero_de_parte & " ' "



           cn2.Open conexion2
           cost = datos2.Fields(2)
           Set datos2 = cn2.Execute(consultaSql2)

       cost = datos2.Fields(2)


        fila_b = fila_b + 1
        fila_c = fila_c + 1
        fila_d = fila_d + 1
        fila_e = fila_e + 1
        fila_f = fila_f + 1
        fila_g = fila_g + 1
        fila_h = fila_h + 1
        fila_i = fila_i + 1
        fila_j = fila_j + 1

    cn2.Close
    Set datos2 = Nothing
    Set cn2 = Nothing

        Loop


        MsgBox "registro actualizado exitosamente!!"
        GoTo update_completo


    Err0r:
    MsgBox "Ingrese todos los campos!!", vbCritical
            Call Module1.limpiarRegistros
            GoTo finalizo_con_error

    update_completo:
    Call Module1.limpiarRegistros

    finalizo_con_error:

    End Sub
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. ¿Has comprobado que la consulta funciona correctamente? ¿Te devuelve registros? Es que tienes puesto `WHERE PartNumber = ' " & 'numero_de_parte & " ' "` entre apóstrofes, y si `PArtNumber` es numérico, quizás podría ser eso. Además, tienes muchas variables sin declarar, siempre es mejor declarar todo para tener un código más fácil de leer y que sea correcto.